# Tracing Recursive Print statements

Tags: java

Could someone help me  trace this recursive print statements to help me understand Recursion.

```
public static void printStuff(int Level) {
   if (level == 0) {
      System.out.print("*");
      } else {
      System.out.print("[");
      printStuff (level-1);
      System.out.print(",");
      printStuff  (level-1);
      System.out.print("]")
   }
}
public static void main (String [] args) {
   printStuff(2);
}
```

Comment: [What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/what-is-a-debugger-and-how-can-it-help-me-diagnose-problems) - If you want a step by step description that walks you through what that code exactly does I'd recommend using a debugger.

Comment: To understand recursion you might want to read articles on it, e.g. [this](https://www.baeldung.com/java-recursion). Basically, you encounter recursion if a method calls itself like `printStuff(...)` is doing. There can be longer "cycles" like `A->B->C->A->B->C...`, i.e. a method can call itself indirectly. Also, to avoid infinite recursion you need some condition when _not_ to do any further recursive calls, like `if (level == 0)`  in your example.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/what-is-a-debugger-and-how-can-it-help-me-diagnose-problems)

Comment: No, that does not help Yerek.  I know how to use a debugger.  The point of the assignment was to trace code that is on paper (no IDE involved), without using an ide or debugger.